# How to Pass Single parameter for below SQL query

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have passed parameter (:PRODUCT_ID) twice. How i can pass :PRODUCT_id only once for below query

```
select count(1)
from (
    select count(1) album_fa_counter
    from actual_configs ac
    where ac.config_id = :PRODUCT_ID
        and exists (
            select 1
            from config_participants cp
            where CONTRIBUTOR_CATEGORY = 'Featured Artist'
                and cp.gpid = ac.gpid
            )
    ) a,
    (
        select count(1) matching_track_fa_counter
        from actual_tracks at1,
            actual_configs ac1
        where at1.gpid = ac1.gpid
            and ac1.config_id = :PRODUCT_ID
            and exists (
                select 1
                from recording_participants rp,
                    config_participants cp
                where cp.CONTRIBUTOR_CATEGORY = 'Featured Artist'
                    and cp.gpid = at1.gpid
                    and cp.participant_name = rp.participant_name
                    and rp.CONTRIBUTOR_CATEGORY = 'Featured Artist'
                    and rp.isrc = at1.isrc
                )
        ) b
where a.album_fa_counter = 0
    or b.matching_track_fa_counter > 0;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without too much modifications to your code, a simple way could be by using a CTE to contain your variable and then use it in join in your query:

```
with yourVariable(val) as ( select :PRODUCT_ID from dual)
select count(1)
from (
    select count(1) album_fa_counter
    from actual_configs ac,
         yourVariable
    where ac.config_id = yourVariable.val
        and exists (
            select 1
            from config_participants cp
            where CONTRIBUTOR_CATEGORY = 'Featured Artist'
                and cp.gpid = ac.gpid
            )
    ) a,
    (
        select count(1) matching_track_fa_counter
        from actual_tracks at1,
            actual_configs ac1,
            yourVariable
        where at1.gpid = ac1.gpid
            and ac1.config_id = yourVariable.val
            and exists (
                select 1
                from recording_participants rp,
                    config_participants cp
                where cp.CONTRIBUTOR_CATEGORY = 'Featured Artist'
                    and cp.gpid = at1.gpid
                    and cp.participant_name = rp.participant_name
                    and rp.CONTRIBUTOR_CATEGORY = 'Featured Artist'
                    and rp.isrc = at1.isrc
                )
        ) b
where a.album_fa_counter = 0
    or b.matching_track_fa_counter > 0;
```

As an aside, I edited your code without rewriting it, but it would be much better to do a little more effort and rewrite it in ANSI SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to solve this like that:

```
With
a as
 (select count(1) album_fa_counter
from actual_configs ac
where ac.config_id = :PRODUCT_ID
    and exists (
        select 1
        from config_participants cp
        where CONTRIBUTOR_CATEGORY = 'Featured Artist'
            and cp.gpid = ac.gpid),

b as
 (
    select count(1) matching_track_fa_counter
    from actual_tracks at1,
        actual_configs ac1,
        a
    where at1.gpid = ac1.gpid
        and ac1.config_id = ac.config_id
        and exists (
            select 1
            from recording_participants rp,
                config_participants cp
            where cp.CONTRIBUTOR_CATEGORY = 'Featured Artist'
                and cp.gpid = at1.gpid
                and cp.participant_name = rp.participant_name
                and rp.CONTRIBUTOR_CATEGORY = 'Featured Artist'
                and rp.isrc = at1.isrc
            )
Select count (1)
from a,b
Where 
a.album_fa_counter = 0
or b.matching_track_fa_counter > 0;
```

Now database sees a and b as real tables, so the parameter you use in a, should be seen as a normal, usable value in a table. 
Hope this works for you.